# The sensibility behind the interchange of limits for a function $g=g(x,h)$ which is continuous at $x=x_0$ and has limit at $h=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be differentiable on $(a,b)\setminus \{c\},$ where $c \in (a,b)$, and $f'$ has limit $\lambda$ at $x=c$. I have to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $c$.

Of course, by mean value theorem, I am convinced in $$\lim_{x \to c^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{\zeta \to c^-}f'(\zeta)=\lambda=\lim_{\eta \to c^+}f'(\eta)=\lim_{x \to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}.$$

Meanwhile, I got another trial,

$$\lim_{x \to c}f'(x)=\lambda \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to c} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lambda \Rightarrow \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lambda$$

$$ \Rightarrow \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=\lambda \Rightarrow f'(c)=\lambda,$$

hold up by the existence of limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h},~0<x<1$ and continuity of $f$.

I feel something misguided in the interchange of limit, Can I interchange the limit while $g(x,h)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ is continuous w.r.t $x$ and has limit at $h=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(x, h)$ is defined and continuous in ${\mathbb R}^2$ except at $(x_0, 0)$, one cannot interchange the limits in general. As an exemple take $g(x, 0) = 0$ and otherwise
\begin{equation}
g(x, h) = \max\left(0, 1 - \left|\frac{x-x_0}{h}\right|\right)
\end{equation}
It is clearly continuous when $h\not = 0$, and it is identically 0 when $h\in (-|x-x_0|, +|x-x_0|)$, hence it is continuous at $(x, 0)$ when $x\not = x_0$.

Comment: What is the role of $x_0$ in my question in which the function $g(x,h)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(x,h) \in \Bbb R^2~:~h = 0\}$?

Comment: I hope you mean by ''$g(x,h)$ is continuous in $\Bbb R^2$ except at $(x_0,0)$'' is $g(x,h)$ is continuous in $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(x_0,0)\} $ rather than $g(x,h)$ is discontinuous at $(x_0,0)$, right?

Comment: The $x_0$ in my reply is actually the $c$ in your question. If you define $g(x, 0)=f'(x)$ for $x \not = c$ and if $f'$ is continuous in ${\mathbb R}\setminus \{c\}$, then $g(x, h)$ is continuous in ${\mathbb R}^2\setminus\{(c, 0)\}$. This is not sufficient to exchange the limits. You need an additional argument (the mean value theorem) here.

Comment: Thanks... I can see the argument supporting the limit interchange is flawed, but how can we explicitly mention the mathematical error in this deduction $\lim_{x \to c}f'(x)=\lambda \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to c} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lambda \Rightarrow \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lambda$, where $f$ is specified in the hypothesis.

Comment: You can just say that the implication is not justified. The error is that there is no argument to justify the exchange of the limits.